# how to handle cache between 2 elixir application nodes?

Tags: elixir

if you are using ConCache or any cache in your application on a very large level and now you are separating your application in 2 different parts to run both on 2 different servers with different IPs.

what will you do about conCache? or cache in short?

1. Switch to third party tool Memcache or Redis
2. Connect both 2 apps with each other using Libcluster and communicate
3. use PubSub or Channels to communicate and share things?

I don't want to switch to any third party tool but to keep everything simple in Elixir, as far as I have heard, You can connect two applications nodes in Elixir and send messages, to which extent it's possible and logical?

Comment: you can create multiple nodes, however make sure that they communicate on an internal network, tcp inter-node communication is not secure, even when using cookie.

Comment: Have you looked at mnesia? https://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html
It works across nodes and allows for in-memory and disk-based persistence.

Comment: [`ConCache`](https://hexdocs.pm/con_cache/ConCache.html) leverages ETS, which means local only. Depending on your requirements, I’d go with either `mnesia` or a set of `Agent`s managed by a cluster.